# Component declartion te be rendered; return value from function vs variable

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to render collection of the components inside ReactDOM render function. When i declare a function that return list of these components everything is fine.

```
const GlobalComponent = () => <React.Fragment><GlobalStyle/><App/></React.Fragment>;
ReactDOM.render(<GlobalComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But when i try to assign `<React.Fragment><GlobalStyle/><App/></React.Fragment>` to object i receive an error.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Wrong code:

```
const GlobalComponent = <React.Fragment><GlobalStyle/><App/></React.Fragment>;
ReactDOM.render(<GlobalComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Could someone explain me why I am unable to assign React component to object?

Comment: You don't need the `< .... />` around `GlobalComponent` in your second example because the component was already created when you assigned it to your `GlobalComponent` variable.

Comment: Check out https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component for more detailed information

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now I can see that with first example (whole GlobalComponent function) was treated as a user-defined component. In fact result of the function is treated same as a variable (instead of `<GlobalComponent />` i should call `GlobalComponent()` which will return `React.Fragment`)

Comment: No, not `GlobalComponent()` just `GlobalComponent`.

Comment: `GlobalComponent` isn't a function, it is a component you created an assigned to a variable. So you pass around the variable just like for any other type.